# ElasticSearch Crashing Repeatedly "HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" despite 4GB ES_MAX_MEM

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm starting ElasticSearch via

```
echo "export ES_HEAP_SIZE = 4096" >> /root/setenv
echo "export ES_MAX_MEM = 4096" >> /root/setenv
echo "export ES_MAX_MEM = 4096" >> /root/setenv

# finally,  we can start the app
echo 'Starting ElasticSearch...'
bin/elasticsearch -Xmx4g -Xms4g
```

However, after no time at all (20min), it becomes unresponsive, apparently due to `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`...

```
[root@ip-***** api]# ps -ax | grep elasticsearch
 6225 ?        SLl    5:35 java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=/root/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.3 -cp :/root/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.3/lib/elasticsearch-0.20.3.jar:/root/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.3/lib/*:/root/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.3/lib/sigar/* -Xmx4g -Xms4g org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch
```

EDIT -- I just noticed that the -Xms size of the output here is just 256m, despite passing 4g in the startup, above. Am I misunderstanding something?

FWIW, I'm on Amazon EC2 (m1.large instances => 8GB of RAM) running CentOS and Java v1.6.0_14-b08

Comment: What kind of queries are you running?

Comment: Define "kind of queries". Here's a typical example of one:
{"size":20,"filter":{"and":[{"range":{"analyzed":{"from":"2013-01-06T18:42:29.232Z"}}}]},"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"test","fields":["title","url"]}}}

Answer (score 4):

First, setting `ES_HEAP_SIZE` won't help you prevent ouf-of-memory errors by itself. The amount of memory used by Elasticsearch is determined by the type of queries you do: whether you use faceting, sorting, filtering, on how many fields, how big are those fields, what is their cardinality, etc.

Second, it's preferable to use the [`ES_INCLUDE`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh) script, or the [service wrapper](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper), instead of passing all the options you need on the command line to the `elasticsearch` script.

Third, when you correctly set the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable, you don't need to pass the `-X` options to the *elasticsearch* script. In fact, these options have no effect -- the script won't pass them to Java. Use the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` variable to control memory, and use the `ES_JAVA_OPTIONS` to control additional variables you would like to pass to Java.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to have ElasticSearch output the ES_HEAP_SIZE, ES_MAX_MEM etc. variables so I can be 100% sure that they're being applied properly? For example, I increased ulimit and used the "-Des.max-open-files=true" flag to output the value, so I could be sure ElasticSearch was "receiving" the change...

Comment: As you mention above, it's immediately visible in the `ps` output. You can see the `heap_max` value in the Cluster Nodes API: http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/?jvm. You can see the `max_file_descriptors` setting there as well: http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/?process

Comment: I think the problem for me here (having the same issue) is that we can't always control the number of searches hitting ES, and therefore can't always accurately predict the memory needs. My question to expand on this is, why does ES crash when it runs out of memory? Can't it manage it's memory better and just refuse queries as it nears it's limit? I'm having to restart it at least twice a week at the moment.